# i want the function of for loop to perform one by one when a key or mouse is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

```
<div id="text">Nature in the broadest sense is the physical world or universe</div>
let el = document.getElementById(text);
let eltext = el.innerText;
let final = eltext.split(" ");
let i;
for (i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {
 if (final[i] === "the") {
   final[i] = `<b>${final[i]}</b>`;
 }
let result = (final + " ").replace(/,/g, " ");
el.innerHTML = result;
```

---

*the result will be:*
Nature in **the** broadest sense is **the** physical world or universe

*what i want:*
when any key is triggered for the first time:
Nature in **the** broadest sense is the physical world or universe

when any key is triggered for the second time:
Nature in the broadest sense is **the** physical world or universe

when any key is triggered for the third time again:
Nature in **the** broadest sense is the physical world or universe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `for` loop, I'd recommend you use built-in `Array` methods for better readability. Here I've extended your sample sentence to show how it can accommodate for longer sentences with more target words.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#text').innerText.split(' ');
const indices = text.map((word, index) => word === 'the' ? index : 0)
  .filter(i => i !== 0);
  
let highlightIndex = 0;

function toggle() {
  const arr = [...text];
  arr[indices[highlightIndex]] = `<strong style="color: red;">${arr[indices[highlightIndex]]}</strong>`;
  document.querySelector('#text').innerHTML = arr.join(' ');
  highlightIndex += 1;
  if (highlightIndex > indices.length -1 ) highlightIndex = 0;
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', toggle);
window.addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

```html
<div id="text">Nature in the broadest sense is the physical world or universe. Introduce the article here for testing the code.</div>
```